# Defining an object with any prop in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, properties

I just switched from JavaScript to TypeScript and am converting a bunch of my code.

I used to use this code a lot in JavaScript (already converted to TypeScript):

```
function isObject (payload: any): payload is object {
  const type: string = Object.prototype.toString.call(payload).slice(8, -1)
  return type === 'Object'
}
```

Then I would do things like this in JavaScript

```
if (isObject(payload) && payload.id) return payload.id
```

However in TypeScript, now it would give me the error that `id` does not exist on `object`.

So instead of returning `payload is object` in my `isObject` function, I think I should return something that is an object with any props with any values.

How can I do this best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define it using an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html), although I'm not sure what benefit you would get from it over `any` since you can index into it with any property, it does not appeat to be any more type-safe then any.

```
function isObject (payload: any): payload is { [name: string]: any} {
    return typeof payload === 'object'; // this should work just the same
}

let payload: any;
if (isObject(payload) && payload.id) payload.id
```

Perhaps if you were to start using strict null checks, one benefit could be that you could remove `undefined` from the result type:

```
function isObject (payload: any): payload is { [name: string]: object | number | string | boolean | undefined} {

    return typeof payload === 'object'
}

let payload: any;
if (isObject(payload) && payload.id) payload.id // payload.id is string | number | true | object here
```

Comment: Dear @Titian Your very first sentence "You can define it using an index signature" is one I do not comprehend. : D mind if you add some extra clarification what that means?

Comment: @mesqueeb added a link to docs, see the Indexable Types section (I can't link directly to it unfortunately)

Comment: Basically you are saying if I want to check if it's an object with any props (which are strings) and any values inside those props, I should use `{[name: string]: any}` instead of `object`. If this is true, I'm really confused what the difference is between TypeScript's `object` vs `{}` eg as explained in this article here: https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2017/02/24/typescript-2-2-the-object-type

Comment: @mesqueeb `object` is a non primitive type. `{}` is a type with no properties (but not necessarily a non primitive). You can assign anything to `{}` (since there are no requirements as to what it should contain) including a `string` or a number, you can't assign a primitive to `object` http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20a%3A%20%7B%7D%0D%0Aa%20%3D%201%0D%0Aa%20%3D%20%22%22%0D%0Alet%20b%3A%20object%3B%0D%0Ab%20%3D%201%0D%0Ab%20%3D%20%22%22

Comment: Two more questions: 1. Is there a difference between `{[key: string]: any}` and `{[name: string]: any}`? 2. does this represent ány amount of props, or just óne prop?

Comment: @mesqueeb 1. No, no difference, just the paramater name, functionally they are the same. 2. it can have any number of props, if you want a specific prop specified as a string you can use mapped types.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181193/discussion-between-mesqueeb-and-titian-cernicova-dragomir).